# EF to POCO - Oracle or SQL Server - Numeric Mapping/Conversion

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, poco

I have a legacy database schema that runs on either SQL Server or Oracle.  I would like to use Entity Framework and a single set of POCOs for the two databases, so I have been working through breaking out the edmx files and using different conceptual and physical definitions for the data.

Where I'm having a problem is with existing numeric data because I can't change the types in the database.  The SQL Server definition is a float and Oracle is a number(19,4), which are reverse engineered to a double and a decimal respectively.

If I change the conceptual model to decimal (which should accommodate either type) I get an error indicating Edm.decimal is not compatible to SqlServer.float. If I leave the conceptual model at the reverse engineered value, then it gives an error saying that the conceptual type doesn’t match with the POCO type (which is decimal since that seemed like it would be compatible with both databases).

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: Decimal and Float do not equate either way, each has numbers that they store exactly which the other type cannot. Regardless one of the types must suit the data you are storing in it, so have you tried changing the type in the Storage Model? I don't believe EF checks it after the initial creation, so you could just change the SQL datatype in the Storage Section to decimal(19,2) and it should work?

Answer (score 0):

My eventual solution to this was to have two fields in the POCO, one to handle Oracle and one SQL Server.  Since the balance of the application (mostly C++) uses a float, the code uses the SQL Server field and the Oracle field just translates to the SQL field for retrieving and saving to the database.  In the Oracle data model, the field is renamed in the logical model so that it uses the translation.

```
public double Value { get; set; }
private decimal ValueDecimal
{
    get{ return (decimal) Value;}
    set{ Value = (double) value;}
}
```

Not necessarily elegant, but I can generate it with a template from the model and it works...